# Getting signalparam of Event in simpy

Tags: python, simpy

I am using SimPy for a time-based simulation.

I have a Messager process which listens for a specific event, and returns the parameters of that event when it occurs:

```
class Messager(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self,'messager')

    def monitor(self):
        while True:
            yield waitevent, self, messageEvent
            print messageEvent.signalparam

messager = Messager()
activate(messager,messager.monitor())
```

this works fine. However, in reality there is more than one Event which should be handled by the Messager, and I want the Messager to return the signalparam for the causative Event in a list of events:

```
messageEvents = [Event1,Event2,Event3]

class Messager(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self,'messager')

    def monitor(self):
        while True:
            yield waitevent, self, messageEvents
            .....
```

how do I access the signalparam of the Event which has occurred?

Comment: why messageEvent.singalparam will not work???? How is second situation different? Can you clarify?

Comment: in the first case, messageEvent is a single Event with a signalparam. In the second case, messageEvents is a list of events. I need to filter the list for the Event which triggered the waitevent. I cannot see a property of these Events which will allow me to determine this.

Comment: So change question to: How to determine if given event triggered waitevent in Python SimPy?

Comment: that's not quite what I'm asking either (but would be a longer way of achieving the same thing). I couldn't think of a brief question title that would capture the whole problem, so I used a slightly simple one.

Comment: Please consider updating to SimPy 3. SimPy 2 is old, out-dated and unmaintained.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of simpy, and specifically of the class Simevent, if you can somehow cast the event to the Simevent class then you should be able to get the attribute signal param out of it.  Not sure if this is possible, but hopefully you know a way to do this.  Good luck.

EDIT:
Just thought of this too, you could edit your simpy and make the Simevent class have a function to get the signalparam.  FYI if you want to do this, the simevent class is located in the lib.py file.

Comment: sorry, should have made it clear - the Events I am referring to are SimEvents, so have signalparam functions. I just can't filter the SimEvents to find out which one I want to read the signalparam from!